# How to keep POST data in Django?

Tags: html, django

I have a code similar to this:

```
<form method="post">
    <!-- INPUTS -->
    <a href="{% url 'app:edit' person.id %}" class="btn btn-gradient-primary">Edit Person</a>
    <a href="{% url 'app:delete' person.id %}" class="btn btn-light">Delete Person</a>
</form>
```

Deletion works because in the `delete` view I only need `person.id`, but editing a person doesn't work because the post data (i.e data from input fields) is lost when clicking the button.

How should I fix this?

Comment: It doesn't seems like you have some data that you're sending with form post. Do you have any input fields?

Comment: I do, I just wanted to make the code as little as possible. 
I know 100% that the input fields work since I've used them before when my code was a bit different.

Comment: You do not submit your form, you are just linking to a url, and thus ommiting the input. You should make a `<button type="submit">`.

Comment: If I turn them into buttons, they no longer seem to redirect the user to the links, even though I added ```onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'app:delete' person.id %}'"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your are not actually sending a form.

Your using two links and sending data to the urls but your are **not** sending the data from the form. This is because of how HTML forms work, when you click the link it will redirect to the page but won't send the data.

What you need is a submit button for your form, something like this

```html
<form method="post" action="{% url 'app:edit' person.id %}">
    <!-- INPUTS -->
    <button type='submit' class="btn btn-gradient-primary">Edit Person</button>
    <a href="{% url 'app:delete' person.id %}" class="btn btn-light">Delete Person</a>
</form>
```

This code will now utilize HTML forms to send the data in a post request which can be accessed in Django via the view receiving it. Example code:

```py
class EditPersonView(View):
  def post(request, person_id):
    form = forms.Person(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid:
      # 'name' is the input of your form
      name = form.cleaned_data['name']
```

That's some basic view code, I highly suggest reading the Django [documentation on  writing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/views/) and also getting familiar with HTML concepts before continuing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sad thing is I've read the documentation on writing views, finished the tutorial and am pretty familiar with HTML concepts. I knew I was missing a type="submit", but I wasn't sure how to have 2 submit buttons, each redirecting to a different links. Apparently, there's no need for that.

Comment: I sympathize, HTML forms are painful to style correctly and I usually just try and avoid having more than one option in a form :D

Answer (score 0):

you may use a submit button to submit the form not a link

try something like:

```html
<form action="{% url 'app:edit' person.id  %}">
      
      <button type="submit">edit</button>
</form>
```